# changing label text and label background color in ASP.MVC WebGrid

Tags: asp.net

I  am rewriting an ASP.NET webform app to ASP.NET MVC. In the webform, there is a gridview with the the following gridview column code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PREV STAT MISSION"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateCompleted" runat="server" ForeColor='<%# Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.Black   %>'   BackColor= '<%# Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1 ? System.Drawing.Color.Green : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 2 ? System.Drawing.Color.Yellow : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 3 ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? System.Drawing.Color.Black : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 5 ? System.Drawing.Color.Blue : System.Drawing.Color.Transparent  %>'      Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1 ? " F1 " : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 2 ? "  F2 " : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 3 ? " F3 " : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? " F4 " : Item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 5 ?  " F5 " : "" %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I  am using ASP.NET MVC WebGrid. So far, I rewritten the code like this

```
grid.Column("PREV_STAT_MISSION", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"></span><label id="lblPrevStatMission" class="edit-mode">
    @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1 ? " F1 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 2 ? "  F2 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 3 ? " F3 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? " F4 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 5 ? " F5 " : "" </label></text>),
```

But it does not work. I am not sure how to change the label text and color using Grid.Column. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1 ? " F1 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 2 ? " F2 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 3 ? " F3 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 4 ? " F4 " : @item.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 5 ? " F5 " : ""
```

change to 
`o => o.PREV_STAT_MISSION == 1?" F1 "` ...

like here `@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("name",format:o => o.Name=="F1"?"F!!":"F22")))`